# Illustrator movement is snapping from pixel to pixel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, configuration

I did something in my illustrator and now everything I try to move isn't moving freely. It's only snaping from pixel to pixel.

Form example, I'm trying to align two object by putting their paths one right next to each other, but since they go from px to px, they go too far or doesn't align.

It's really annoying because if I'm trying to put, for example, 2 anchor points on top of each other, it never matches the position. On the image below my mouse is right on top of the other anchor point, but the point being moved is way up.

I already tried to delete users preferences but it didn't worked as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to turn off Align to Pixel grid options. Specifically Snap to Grid. To do this, go to the menu>View>Snap to Grid, near the bottom. If you have this checked, your anchor points will snap to the nearest grid line. Uncheck it to prevent this.

Next go to menu>View>Snap to Point, and make sure it's checked to allow your anchor points to snap to each other when moved close enough together (*can change this in Preferences>Selection & Anchor Display*).

Comment: I also had to uncheck Snap to Pixel to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: you dont need to disable gridsnapping unless your grid is actually 1 pixel sized just the pixelsnap